# Toggle a model based on a search string result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

What I'm trying to do is find a simple way to toggle a model based on a search string results, I made a quick concept example to help visualize;

> [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qbe4q41g/)

I have a toggle button within each item that has its model `blah` in the example provided.

What I keep failing at is figuring out a way to say for example if search=name.phone then blah=false or essentially use the search string to toggle the square to red if the string used to search is name.phone and it's in the search results, that at least conveys the concept hopefully.

The reality is I have parts within the item template that are potentially hidden at first but they would still yield a search result but aren't visible in result. So I want them visible to the user if they're what was searched for. Makes sense right?

I was hoping it was possibly as simple as something like;

```
 <div ng-class="{'style-it red':blah,
                 'style-it green':!blah,
                 'style-it red':search=name.phone}"></div>
```

..or something like it. Or maybe an inline ternary from the search input or something? I could show more failed attempts but they're obviously the wrong way anyway since I'm asking so I'll save the space. Oh and before you even think about down-voting or something give me an explanation why at least and go check out my Q/A ratio to understand you'd be helping someone who helps others often. I welcome a slice of humble pie in the name of learning.

Comment: What's the exact logic scenario you're after? `search == name.phone` will work (provided you remember the second `=`). If this is in a repeater, use `ng-init` to check the `search` value and set `blah` -- `ng-init="blah = search == name.phone"`

Comment: Rather than use ng-class I would have a green box and a red box and use ng-show to toggle the correct box. That ng-show criteria could be based off both a model value and the search value.

Comment: The exact scenario is say I have a div inside the item that by default is not shown. It has a model to toggle its visibility. Say it holds a phone number for example. If you do a search, it will still pull up that item but that phone number may not be immediately visible to the user. So I want it to toggle that model to true or false if that part is what was used as search, make sense? Looks like I may have to tinker some more obviously, and down-votes don't bother me a bit while I'm transitioning to a new syntax.

Comment: So, you want to know which property is causing it to show in the filtered list?

Comment: @Eterm that's exactly what I'm doing in the real scenario, but so far I have not been able to hit it with that criteria...

Comment: @Delta nah I know why it shows, but I'm looking for a way to take that resulting string that caused the filtering and toggle a model's bool with it. I may not be explaining this as well as I thought lol.

Comment: @AtymeJV if you have some time and care to elaborate, that ng-init idea sounds like it may do but I wasn't able to get it thus far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question was a bit unclear, but if you are wanting to toggle something based on whether you have an exact match you'll want to use ng-show to control visibility.

As demonstrated in:   https://jsfiddle.net/7by52qhh/1/

```
<span ng-show="name.name === search">Exact Match!</span>
```

This will appear in the names repeater when there is an exact match.

This could of course show other model data, I have left it as some static text here for clarity.

Comment: +1 Simply because it's REALLY close and is actually something I can use elsewhere. Except I'm trying to figure out a way where if say the name.phone=555-1234 and they search for 1234 which still gives them the item, then it would also flip a model to true to interact with the div that holds the phone number and make it ng-show=true, the problem is that div already has a ng-show handling the toggling of its visibility by a button in the item......lol if this was c#/xaml I'd never have to ask so I appreciate the help either way!

Comment: Don't over-complicate, don't try to toggle visibility with the model just toggle it with an  ng-show with multiple criteria. Or use modelValue && (expression)

Comment: Well shoot, I thought I was under-complicating it . I've got some tabs created, clicking one shows/hides a div while setting the models on the others to false so only one is shown at a time. I tried something on the divs being hidden/shown like `ng-show="ToggleButtonModel || search==name.phone" ` but no joy. I may have to think this out some more since your way requires an exact match to string and type and what I'm aiming for is if say the search result is found using just the last 4 digits of the phone or just a first name, still throw a bool I can use to ng-show those panels the info sits

Comment: Could you update your question to state your intent then please? I think my latest version of my fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/7by52qhh/2/ captures it. It shows "exact match" when either you press the button or match the last 4 numbers.

Comment: HOLY CRAP! Kudos to you sir haha if there's any indication to how new to js stuff I am, I didn't even consider using substr like that!!! Absolutely awesome!! Thank you sir, a beer is most definitely owed because you just gave me a pivot point I can use to do some other really cool stuff! Cheers! I'm going to go swallow my slice of humble pie now.... ;)